# braintree.Transaction.Status does not exist in braintree-node

Tags: node.js, braintree

According to [this article](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/search/node) the Braintree object should have Transaction.Status and then under that Accepted and others.  But when I try to run code containing this I get the error: `Cannot read property 'Status' of undefined`

Has this been pulled out of the current API?  If so what has replaced it?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the problem here is that I was using [this package](https://github.com/varunjayaraman/braintree-node) which uses promises for my gateway.  I thought that the same package would work for Braintree, but I needed to `npm i braintree` and use that instead.